# Ubuntu 22.04 very long log in

Tags: gnome, login, snap

Logging into the system takes about 10-20 seconds even if the screen was locked a second ago. Sometimes it showed "snapd user session agent", when I removed snap the problem was gone, then when i needed snap and reinstalled it everything was ok, but after a day the issue returned. I use default gnome3

Comment: For which application do you need snap?

Comment: Gnome 3 with 22.04? That is not what 22.04 ships with. Therefore it is not the default.

Comment: just checked, its gnome 42.5 idk why i thought its gnome3.

I used snap to install spotify, vs code

Comment: Workaround: Both of them can be installed without snap https://www.spotify.com/us/download/linux/ and https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/?dv=linux64_deb